# create table name with other table column and sequence number oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Creating a clear log procedure, which deletes and insert into a backup table everyday, what I need to do is after the backup table reaches a certain number of rows, I want my job(procedure) to create a new table with the same fields.

So I have a table config with the tables I need to backup identified , and I have a column named `pre_bck` which has the name I want my back up table to have.

So I want to try to make a procedure that will create a table from that `'column'+the sequence number`

```
create table 'column_name'+sequence_id as select * from xyz where 1=0;
```

so for example if table name was abc and sequece id was 3, table name would be abc3

I dont know if I was clear, as to what I pretend to implement, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle <> MySQL. Please dont spam tag various RDBMS.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The only reason I can think of is to make dropping old data easier - so have you considered partitioning a single table instead? But you're deleting and inserting... how will that work the day after you created a new table, is it supposed to delete all matching tables, or delete the original one and drop the others? This seems like an odd set-up to me, anyway...

Comment: Basically we want to keep all data in backup, after a while we want to export those tables we created. the idea is to always have our original table with few records to make our application run faster. The method is the one i was asked to create.

Comment: the job will run daily, so for example table abc will insert into abc_bck where sysdate-30, after abc_bck reaches say 1M rows i want to create a abc_bck2 and do the same process again

Comment: I second Alex's suggestion of partitioning the table. You can then drop old partitions / exchange them with empty tables as necessary. By keeping the data in partitions (e.g. range partitioned by a date column), so long as your queries query for rows after some date, then you can take advantage of partition pruning. E.g. say you partitioned weekly, you could query for records in the past week, and you'd retrieve rows from at most 2 partitions.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Partitioning is a chargeable extra on the Enterprise Edition license. So many places don't have that option. However, Flashback Data Archive has been part of plain old EE since 11.2.0.4, which would be a better solution to an archiving requirement.

Comment: *"what I need to do is after the backup table reaches a certain number of rows, I want my job(procedure) to create a new table with the same fields."* . So how will you know which table has any given row? If you can't retrieve the data it's not a backup in any meaningful sense.

Comment: I dont need to retrieve the data, its just in case something happens, i need to have it stored somewhere. I will have a close_date field on each table i create, so i will know where to look in case i need to search for something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second Alex and Boneist's opinion that this is probably not a good approach.

However, to answer your question:

The operator to glue together various bits of a string is `||`, not `+` as in other languages: `column_name || sequence_id`.

To execute SQL from within a procedure, you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE ...';`

To select from a sequence, you need to create it with `CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence;`. To get a value: `my_sequence.nextval`.

The easiest way to loop over all rows in your config table is a `FOR IN ... LOOP`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure IS
  stmt VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM my_config_table ORDER BY xxx) LOOP
    stmt := 'CREATE TABLE ' || pre_bck || my_sequence.nextval || 
            ' AS SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE 1=0';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
  END LOOP;
END my_procedure;
/
```

I'm not clear what the `xyz` part means, but you can surely take it from here...

Comment: that is it, the xyz was just a example of a the original table name.
thank you, i will try work with that, looks like its exactly what i need. If it was up to me i would use Alex and Boneist's approach but its not.

Comment: where i have pre_bck could i use for example table1.column1?

Comment: The content of `stmt` must be valid SQL. Just put together the pieces you need. After `CREATE TABLE`, the name of the new table is expected. Full docu is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402)